# How to create a view model from a model interface in MVVM style?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, model, viewmodel

I'm using a view model first approach and in some models I expose other models via an interface like this:

```
public class ModelA : IModel {}
public class ModelB : IModel {}
// plus yet unknown additional models

public class ViewModelA : IViewModel 
{
    ViewModelA(ModelA model){}
}
// a model may have several possible view models that should be selectable somehow
public class ViewModelAVariant : IViewModel 
{
    ViewModelAVariant(ModelA model){}
}
public class ViewModelB : IViewModel {}
{
    ViewModelA(ModelB model){}
}

public class ModelContainer
{
    public IModel[] SubModels { get { return new IModel { new ModelA(), new ModelB()};}}
}

public class ViewModelContainer
{
    private ModelContainer modelContainer;

    public IViewModel[] SubModels
    {
        get
        {
            return modelContainer.SubModels.Select( sm =>  ToViewModel(sm)).ToArray();
        }
    }


    private IViewModel ToViewModel(IModel model)
    {
        // what to insert here?
    }

}
```

### Possible solutions

#### Variant 1:

Store a collection of `IModel` to `IViewModel` converters and use them in the ViewModel.

```
private IDictionary<type,Func<IModel,IViewModel>> converters;
private IViewModel ToViewModel(IModel model)
{
    return converters[model.GetType()](model);
}
```

Pros:

- The model does not have to know about the view models
- It's possible to select a ViewModels

Cons:

- The process may fail at runtime if there is no suitable converter

#### Variant 2:

```
interface IModel
{
    IViewModel ToViewModel();
}

public class ModelA : IModel 
{
    // this enables view model selection
    public ModelA(Func<ModelA,IViewModel> converter)
    {
        this.converter = converter;
    }
    private Func<ModelA,IViewModel> converter;
    public IViewModel ToViewModel()
    {
        return converter(this);
    }
}
```

Pros:

- It's possible to select a ViewModels
- easy to use, hard to misuse

Cons:

- The model has to know about the view models

I'm looking for a variant without the drawbacks.

Comment: May I ask why you're doing this? A viewmodel should know its model, there's no need to abstract that. And one model doesn't necessarily correlate to a single viewmodel, several viewmodels could be using the same model...

Comment: "The model has to know about the view models" There's a point where following a design pattern becomes a cargo cult.  I think if you're worried about this you should start building airplanes out of bamboo.

Comment: @almulo I absolutely agree with you. A view model should know it's model. But my question is how how to create a view model from a model via a model interface, especially when there are several view models to choose from.

Comment: Ur... You can`t? >_< Don't get me wrong, I'm not saying you shouldn't go it if you know what you're doing and it is what you need, but what you're trying to do doesn't make much sense in a MVVM architecture, so you might as well go for variant 2, as @Will says.

Comment: If you automatically create view models from model types, chances are that the view model you end up with is not really doing anything a view model does (providing the whole logic) but just a (useless) wrapper for the model. In general, you don’t want to create view models based on the selection of some model but rather want to explicitely create a view model (since you’re building some view) at which point the view model may load one or more models.

Comment: @poke For some models there are several options for view models and the application chooses one depending on configuration. In the proposed variants it's not up to the model to decide which ViewModel to choose (the function that "decides" is injected in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a good use case for [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started).

Basically you would create a configuration, in it's simplest case it's:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ModelA, ViewModelA>();
Mapper.CreateMap<ModelA, ViewModelAVariant<>();
Mapper.CreateMap<ModelB, ViewModelB>();
```

This assumes that all properties are named same (in both ViewModel and Model). It can also flatten properties, i.e. `ModelA.Property` is mapped, by convention to `ModelAProperty` if it exists.

If you have more complex mappings, you have to configure the mappings.

Then resolve it via

```
ModelA modelA = ... // retrieve ModelA 
ViewModelA viewModelA = Mapper.Map<ViewModelA>(modelA);
```

and for variations:

```
ModelA modelA = ... // retrieve ModelA 
ViewModelAVariation viewModelA = Mapper.Map<ModelA, ViewModelAVariation>(modelA);
```

You shouldn't use it the other way though, at least it's not recommended to convert from ViewModel to Domain/Business Model. It's main goal is for Model to DTO (Data Transfer Objects) or Model to ViewModel mappings.

Comment: Sounds like a global approach for variant 2. Another problem is that when I retrieve a `ModelA`, the type information I have is only `IModel`!

Comment: You can also use the non-generic versions of `Mapper.Map` which accept parameters of type `Type` which you can get via `modelA.GetType()`